# How to 301 a URL without a query string to a different URL with a query string

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This isn't ideal for SEO reasons -- but I have little choice:

I'm trying to redirect 50 URLs, one for each of our United Sates, like so, from:

```
http://www.example.com/411/states/Alabama.html
```

to

```
https://example.com/wp/myfolder?search_field=state&value=AL
```

Beyond forwarding to a different URL, there are three things I also need to accomplish:

1. Add the query string
2. Force the use of `https` regardless of whether or not `https` or `http` was contained in the original URL
3. It shouldn't matter whether a visitor enters the "www" or not.

There are plenty of online examples showing the opposite (URL with query > URL without query) - but I couldn't find one going this direction.

I've tried quite a few combinations, most recently:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^\.mydomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^411/states/Alabama\.html$ https://example.com/wp/myfolder\?search_field=state&value=AL [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're having the same problem, here's what worked for me:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/411/states/Arkansas\.html$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/wp/file-name?search_field=state&value=AR [R=301,L]
```

Comment: The rule you had in the question is "better" (you just needed to remove the `RewriteCond` directive). You should check the URL-path in the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ (as you did in the question) not in an additional `RewriteCond` directive.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^\.mydomain\.com$
> RewriteRule ^411/states/Alabama\.html$ https://example.com/wp/myfolder\?search_field=state&value=AL [L,R=301]
> ```

This is basically correct, you just need to remove the `RewriteCond` directive (it will never match, but would not seem to be required anyway). The literal `?` in the *substitution* string does not need to be backslash-escaped (but its not a problem either).

There is no special treatment required when redirecting from a URL without a query string (or one where you are not concerned about the query string) to a URL with a query string. Just state the target URL as written.

However, for this specific problem of redirecting all 50 states... you could instead use just a single rule and use 50 conditions (`RewriteCond` directives), one for each state, to *look-up* the "state code". This would help to avoid repetition and would be more efficient since there is only one rule to process, not 50.

(I've assumed the `411` part of the URL is just an arbitrary numeric code, different for each URL and not required for a successful match.)

For example:

```
RewriteCond $1/AL ^Alabama/(..) [OR]
RewriteCond $1/AK ^Alaska/(..) [OR]
RewriteCond $1/AZ ^Arizona/(..) [OR]
RewriteCond $1/AR ^Arkansas/(..) [OR]
RewriteCond $1/CA ^California/(..) [OR]
: etc.
RewriteCond $1/WA ^Washington/(..) [OR]
RewriteCond $1/WV ^West-Virginia/(..) [OR]
RewriteCond $1/WI ^Wisconsin/(..) [OR]
RewriteCond $1/WY ^Wyoming/(..)
RewriteRule ^\d+/states/([\w-]+)\.html$ https://example.com/wp/file-name?search-field=state&value=%1 [R=301,L]
```

The `$1` backreference contains the "state name" as captured from the URL-path. The `(..)` in the *CondPattern* captures the corresponding 2 character "state code" from the *TestString*.

The `%1` backreference contains the matched "state code". Specifically, this contains the first captured group from the last matched *CondPattern*. All the *conditions* are `OR`'d; only one can match.

Note that the last *condition* (`RewriteCond` directive) does not have an `OR` flag.

(This doesn't specifically check for an empty query string, as that does not seem to be necessary.)